# REPLACE NULL WITH 0 when pivot clause is used

Tags: sql-server

I have a below query

```
WITH MAIN AS (
SELECT CATEGORY,LBRCODE,STATECODE,DISTCODE,BLOCKCODE,ATMYN X  FROM Sheet1$ 
UNION 
SELeCT CATEGORY,LBRCODE,STATECODE,DISTCODE,BLOCKCODE,MOBILEVAN  X FROM Sheet1$ WHERE MOBILEVAN='Y'
)
,
BLOCK AS (
SELECT * FROM Sheet1$
)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT STATECODE,DISTCODE,BLOCKCODE,CATEGORY,ISNULL(atm,0) atm FROM (
SELECT a.STATECODE,a.DISTCODE,a.BLOCKCODE,a.CATEGORY,
sum(CASE WHEN b.X ='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) atm
FROM BLOCK a LEFT JOIN MAIN b ON a.LBRCODE=b.LBRCODE
GROUP BY a.STATECODE,a.DISTCODE,a.BLOCKCODE,a.CATEGORY
) x
) y
pivot ( sum(atm) FOR CATEGORY  IN ( [RURAL] , [SEMI URBAN] , [URBAN]) 
) a
```

It runs fine only it giving me null values
how do I replace null with 0?

Comment: `ISNULL`, or `COALESCE`.

Comment: if I try isnull or coalesce at this lin 'pivot ( sum(atm) FOR CATEGORY  IN ( [RURAL] , [SEMI URBAN] , [URBAN]) ' i get error

Comment: You need it in the final `SELECT` in place of `SELECT *` you should have all columns specified with `ISNULL`

Comment: They go in the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: FYI, as well, white space and line breaks would make your life *far* easier. That SQL is quite hard to read, as it's impossible to easily tell where all the sub queries start and end.